# What are the use cases of Apex Test class other than code coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test

1. What are the use cases of Apex Test class other than code coverage ?
2. For configuration task such as workflow/process builder/approval process, can we use apex test class to verify the output as expected?

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend you read **[How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)** (emphasis mine):

> ## [The Value of Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#The_Value_of_Unit_Tests)
>
> *One of the most valuable benefits of unit tests is that they give you confidence that your code works as you expect it to work*. Unit tests give you the confidence to do long-term development because with unit tests in place, you know that your foundation code is dependable. Unit tests give you the confidence to refactor your code to make it cleaner and more efficient.
>
> Unit tests also save you time because unit tests help prevent regressions from being introduced and released. Once a bug is found, you can write a unit test for it, you can fix the bug, and the bug can never make it to production again because the unit tests will catch it in the future.
>
> Another advantage is that unit tests provide excellent implicit documentation because they show exactly how the code is designed to be used.

See also (emphasis mine):

> #### [Verify the results are correct](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct)
>
> *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing.* It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.

As for whether or not you *can* unit test declarative functionality, obviously yes. But should you? I say no. In general you should only write unit tests for your code. You should cover declarative functionality using *functional testing*, where you have humans walk through the user flow and verify behavior. This same testing approach should *also* be used for your code changes, if you have the resources.

Comment: Just to add if a wfr is used in lieu of code and is business directed and augments your code and should not change I would submit a unit test ensuring that functionality does not change would be wise

Comment: @Eric Unit testing against `Process Builder` flows are tricky since the flow deploys inactive. I would advise against in most cases. As for workflow...

Comment: Yea good point. I took that out. I still think there are use cases for testing wfr by asserting behavior to ensure no one messes with the ones they should not

Comment: @Eric Sounds like you have a good opinion to express via Answer. :) Technically the question asks if we *can*, not if we *should*, but so far everyone has answered both. I'm in the *should not* camp, but there are few absolutes in this business.

Answer (score 4):

Unit tests are **not** intended for code coverage. We are forced to get code coverage as an indication that we spent the time to try and verify our logic works correctly. The **only** purpose of unit tests is to make sure that we deploy code which will not crash/produce incorrect behavior for our users. This means **setting up** test data, **running** the methods, and then **verifying** the output. If you are only writing a unit test for code coverage, you're doing yourself and your users a disservice.

You could unit test workflow rules and so on, but in practice, this is not necessary and is probably burdensome. However, if you had a few critical processes that you wanted to make sure were protected, you might consider writing unit tests for them. Always remember that *code coverage* is a *side effect* of good unit tests, not the purpose.

Comment: Code coverage is a side effect. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

1. As a supplement to the other answers, consider that test cases are a fantastic safety net when you work on your code. All code changes over time, but normally the aim is to not break existing functionality when adding new functionality. Few of us have the willpower to manually test that we haven't broken anything and that is where *automated* unit tests come in because the automation does all the work. We run all tests on every checkin through a Continuous Integration setup so at this point tests written several years ago have confirmed nothing is broken thousands of times which is great payback. Manual testing is way, way more expensive and time consuming (and tedious).
2. Yes you can use Apex tests though sometimes features are quite hard to test due to lack of appropriate APIs. If some behavior is important to your business (and not going to change frequently) then a unit test to confirm it is working is appropriate. Just because the platform doesn't mandate that you have a unit tests doesn't mean that you can't use one. I've often added unit tests for SObject formula fields, particular complex ones as a natural part of the development process: better to write down the test cases in a test than on a piece of paper that gets lost.

Comment: I have seen tests against complex formulas introduce *so much pain* into the deployment process, though.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm coming at this from the managed package side where I haven't seen any pain; interested in any example you have of where it causes trouble.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what it was and it was years ago, but it forced some poor soul into 2AM deployments where they had to actually turn some rules off...that org was a mess.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah its hard not to run into other people's logic when manipulating SObjects in tests, but a test on a formula field is likely to just be one of many tests that touch an important SObject.

Answer (score -3):

From Salesforce point of view, we write test class for code coverage only, but if we don't focus on code coverage, it's still a good practice to test all your apex code behaviour with unit tests. That's why good programmers focus on 100% code coverage just to make sure that all use cases are being tested by unit tests.

Yes you can write test classes to test the expected output from workflow, process builders or approval processes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is not Salesforce's point of view. They practically shout from the rooftops that coverage is not the key aim of testing.

Comment: Also 100% code coverage doesn't ensure that "all use cases are being tested". Coverage ensures a line of code ran in one circumstance not that all the permutations of the use cases ran and produced the expected result.

Comment: My controllers often have the line `if(!Test.isRunningTest()){stdc.addFields(...);}`, which will always be covered and never tested.  Code coverage is a functionally useless metric, it's just easy to use to satisfy an automated requirement that a class has at least had lip service paid to being tested.